# Update software on 3Com Baseline Switch 2928-SFP Plus

Tags: switch, 3com, firmware-update

I would like to update my 3Com Baseline Switch 2928-SFP Plus (Device Name: 3CRBSG2893) but can't figure out how to find it on HP's site.

The model has been incorporated into HP's line of switches and [HP's My Networking Page](https://h10145.www1.hpe.com/support/SupportLookUp.aspx) doesn't seem to list this model.

I read that HP have incorporated the 3Com firmware into their own line but the ability to search by 3Com's models does not seem to have been carried forward.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I found my answer on HPE's page [Firmware for Baseline 2928 (V1910-24G)](https://community.hpe.com/t5/Web-and-Unmanaged/Firmware-for-Baseline-2928-V1910-24G/td-p/5380447#.YcGd-GjMKUl).  This answers my query but anyone with a different model would essentially have to either find someone who has already asked the question or ask their question on HPE's forum.

It would be great if a cross referenced list could be available on HPE's site.

Comment: Hopefully, that someone will stumble upon your post and find that information here. HPE is notorious for not referencing legacy products properly, sadly.